# Difference between "convergence in measure" and "convergence almost everywhere"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the following two definitions:

Definitions:
$f_n$ converges in measure to $f$ if for every $\epsilon >0 $
$\mu ({x: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon}) \rightarrow 0$.

A sequence of functions $f_n$ converges almost everywhere to $f$ if there is a set of measure $0$ such that for $x$ not in this set we have $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$.

So if I want to show that a sequence convergec in measure, I consider the set $\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}$ and show that its measure converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Now my problem is, if I want to show that a sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere, then I have to show that the set $\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\frac{1}{n}\}$ has measure $0$.

So the only difference is that in "convergence in measure", there is a sequence of sets $A_n:=\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}$ and I have to show that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n =0$. And in "convergence almost everywhere" there is the set, of points where $f_n(x) \nrightarrow f(x)$, and show that this set which does not depend on $n$ has measure $0$.

Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Convergence in measure does not imply pointwise convergence. For example, consider functions which are $1$ on a segment of the length $1/n$ in unit interval and make this segment move from $0$ to $1$ with $n$ back 
and forth. Such sequence converge in measure to $0$ but is nowhere convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, define the set $A_{n,m}:= \{ x \mid |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{m} \}$.

Now let $B := \{ x \mid \text{for every $m$}, |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{m} \text{whenever $n$ is big enough} \} $

$f_n$ converges in measure if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu( A_{m,n}) = 0$ for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

$f_n$ converges almost everywhere if and only if $B$ is measure $0$.

Maybe this can help you develop some intuition.